# Knowing the possibility of three independent events, is there a way to calculate the following properties?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

If we know the P of three independent events $A,B,C$, then 
how can we calculate $P(A \cup B \mid C)$ and 
$P((A \cup C) \cap (B^c \cup C)\mid C)$?

Is it valid to say that given $A$ and $B$ are independent to $C$, then $A \cup B$ is independent to $C$ as well?

Comment: You've used "N" in your expression; by this, do you mean "intersection"?

Comment: Yes. So I am trying to calculate the intersection between A union C and B complement union C.

Comment: Well $C\subseteq (A\cup C)\cap (B^{c}\cup C),$ so the second probability is 1.

Comment: Can you explain how you got this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessarily true that if $A$ and $C$ are independent, and $B$ and $C$ are as well, then $A \cup B$ is independent of $C$. Here's a counterexample:

[image: Venn diagram]

Note that each pair of events is independent, but $P((A \cup B) \cap C) \neq P(A \cup B) \cdot P(C)$. This implies that even for events that are pairwise independent, $P(A \cup B | C)$ is not a function of $P(A), P(B), P(C)$.

RideTheWavelet was also correct that the second expression is just 1.

Comment: does that mean we can't calculate the probability of AUB|C if all the individual P is given, because P((A∪B)∩C)≠P(A∪B)⋅P(C)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: can you also explain a little more why the second expression is 1? How can you say that C⊆(A∪C)∩(Bc∪C)?

Comment: Let $x \in C$. Then it is true that $x \in A \cup C$, and it is also true that $x \in B^c \cup C$. Hence, $x$ is in $(A \cup C) \cap (B^c \cup C)$, whence $C \subset (A \cup C) \cap (B^c \cup C)$. From this it follows that $C \cap [(A \cup C) \cap (B^c \cup C)] = C$, and thus, $P((A \cup C) \cap (B^c \cup C) | C) = P(C | C) = 1$.

Comment: I understand everything except this C∩[(A∪C)∩(Bc∪C)]=C. Why do we need the union here? Thank you!

Comment: The unions in the brackets? I just copied those from the set you wrote. Or did you mean the *intersection* on the left? That one is because $P( S | C) = P ( S \cap C) / P(C) $, where $S$ is your set.